# Validating form in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I am working on Redmine and using Ruby on rails. Now, I need to put validation for form. Do I need to edit model or controller for validating form?

Answer (score 4):

Usually validations go into the model, but don't forget that the controller will need to allow certain parameters to be passed through to the model itself with the [`permit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) method.

It's the controller's job to attempt to create or update models, then define the behaviour for what happens if that doesn't work out. That might be to display an error page, or to send a failed API call response. It depends on what you're building.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're looking to validate; but as `tadman` suggested, you'll want to keep to convention and [**define the validations in the model**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Why do this?

The answer is simple - [**MVC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

[image]

When you send data to your Rails app, the `controller` simply organizes the data & sends it to the model. The model's job is to then validate, save & return the processed data as an `object` (as per Ruby's OOP structure).

--

**Model**

Rails' [inbuilt validators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) work on model level (I.E once you've received the data through your controller, you pass it to the model - *it* then validates it):

```
#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :attribute, presence: true
end
```

If your data does not pass this validation, it will basically return the object to your controller, which will then render the respective view (probably one with the errors showing).

So to answer your question, you should definitely look at validating in your **`model`**

Comment: and Tadman, thank you for your answer. I could figure it out. Needed to add the fields in 'validates_presence_of :'of models's rb file. Then in view did required => true. It is working fine. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/views/issues. Then edit _attributes.html.erb by removing ":required => true" from an attribute that I want to validate. After that, I have edited
 validates_presence_of :subject, :priority, :project, :tracker, :author, :status
from issues.rb file of model. Here I can add or delete fields that I want to include or exclude. 
In this way, I solved the problem....